# .NET Bundling - 404 when Enable Optimizations true

Tags: asp.net, .net, bundling-and-minification

I'm having an issue when `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` is set, the virtual URLs are returning 404s. This happens for both my JS and CSS bundles. Here is an example of a bundle I have:

```
  BundleTable.Bundles.Add(
      new StyleBundle("~/css")
          .Include("~/ui/basic/foundation.css")
          .Include("~/ui/basic/all.css")
          .Include("~/ui/basic/print.css")
      );
```

I have tried changing the bundle name/path to random characters to be sure that it was definitely not an existing path. I also tried adding bundle to my modules by:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="BundleModule" />
        <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
```

I have bundling running in the same fashion on another project locally which is all working fine.

If anyone has any ideas what it could be that is causing the issue I would greatly appreciate the help.

PS: the project is sitecore using forms. (Same as the other project which is working fine)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Form authentication on every page, you have to give permissions to the virtual directory that is created by the bundles. Even if that directory **does not** physically exists.

I had a similar problem once, it was resolved here:

[Bundle Minification not working when publishing WebForms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908806/bundle-minification-not-working-when-publishing-webforms-app/19934804#19934804)