# Bundle Minification not working when publishing WebForms App

Tags: c#, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to use bundle minification for some .css and .js files. My bundle config is the following:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr.js"
        ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/TemplateContent").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Content/prettyPhoto.css",
            "~/Content/prettify.css",
            "~/Content/flexslider.css",
            "~/Content/iview.css",
            "~/Content/style.css",
            "~/Content/default.css"
        ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/AppContent").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap-tablesorter.css",
            "~/Content/animate.css",
            "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
            "~/Content/jcarousel.css",
            "~/Conten/overwrite.css",
            "~/Content/sequence.css",
            "~/Content/sequence.ie.css",
            //more styles
        ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/TemplateScripts").Include( 
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
            "~/Scripts/raphael.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/google-code-prettify/prettify.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.elastislide.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.tweet.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js",
            "~/Scripts/iview.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-hover-effect.js",
            "~/Scripts/animate.js",
            "~/Scripts/custom.js"
        ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/AppScripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.ticker.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.contenthover.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js",
            "~/Scripts/datetimepicker.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.metadata.js",
            //more scripts
        ));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

The problem happens when I publish the app to a server (godaddy shared web hosting), I do get a minified output, but I get 403 errors on those outputs.

If I set

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

The files are not minified but the page has the correct behavior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out it was ASP.NET form authentication. As according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673759/mvc4-style-bundle-giving-403), the name of the bundle should not be an existing directory. And well, forms authentication denies access to those directories that are not allowed int the web.config.

I did not know that the bundles create their own directory, so I basically added the location tag for those directories (even though they are not physically in the solution).

So basically...

For all of the previous bundles names, I added "~/bundles/" and then created the following location tag in the web.config:

```
<location path="bundles">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thank you! What I did was changed the path in my bundle config. I updated my view layout accordingly, and then scratched my head a bunch trying to figure out why it still wouldn't work. I finally realized I had updated the bin files on my site but not the layout that was calling  the old bundle path.

Comment: Fixed the issue for the `asp.net mvc` project i am working on. Thank you!

Comment: For my Webforms application, the lack of the above `location` exception, caused my application to not work on anything besides Chrome. I don't understand how is this not added into the `Web.config` by default when creating the project.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't try to bundle minified scripts, it should work. Sometimes if you have written javascript and you missed a semicolon, this could cause the scripts to fail when calling them, but not throw a 403 error.

Since you get a 403 error i'm guessing that this is not related to the bundling. Can you show the exact error? Is it a 403.2: Read access forbidden? Or is it when you try to publish to your site (403.3: Write access forbidden)? The best setup when developing is to have your local IIS setup properly so that you can bundle and publish a release to your local machine. If this works then all you need to do is to copy your files from your local machine to the public server. If something is wrong on the public server, then you know that it's a configuration error on that machine, and not a code problem.

My best guess is that you are not allowed to publish your application to your site (you get write access denied for some folders), but without further information it's really hard to say.

**EDIT:** After reading a little more about bundling I'm almost certain that you are bundling a script to an existing folder.

*Every request in ASP.NET is manged through http handlers(for example, static handler, page handler, ashx handler, etc). There is a special HTTP Module called UrlRoutingModule which matches the routes in global.asax. If a route is match then it will chnage the current http handler using HttpContext.RemapHandler method otherwise normal ASP.NET flow will continue. Similarly System.Web.Optimization insert a BundleModule http module which try to match a binding. If a match is found found then it will select the BundleHandler as http handler using HttpContext.RemapHandler method. Internally System.Web.Optimization will leave a match if HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists(path) is true or HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.DirectoryExists(path) is true.*

[Read the whole thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1810635.aspx)

With this said, make all bundles start with **"~/bundles/"**. This will ensure that the script will not point to a folder that exists or get caught by your routeconfiguration.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(...
```

Comment: Hi, I thought exactly that and gave read and write permissions to the directory in IIS but the problem persisted. Then I disabled optimizations and the app worked, hence I discarded the issue on the server.

The weirdest part is that I published an MVC application with the exact configuration and it worked perfectly, didn't even have to give extra permissions in IIS.

Also, I'm using Forms Authentication, and I am giving access to the directories in the location tags of the web config, so that's not either.

Comment: AFTER EDIT: I had read about the issue here: stackoverflow.com/questions/13673759/… But that wasn't it either. I figured it out, turns out it was ASP.NET Form Authentication, check my answer for more detail.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My script bundle was failing due to **dots in the bundle name**, which explains why it worked in debug (since there is no real bundling there) and failed in when released..

BEFORE (failing)

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/My.Corp.Scripts").Include(...
```

AFTER (fixed)

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MyCorpScripts").Include(...
```

Don't forget to update your razor references to use the fixed bundle name